# Dell PowerEdge SC1425 - Boot Error from USB

Tags: ubuntu, dell-poweredge, usb, bios

I'm new to hosting, and I got my first server a couple of days ago, and am having troubles.
I'm trying to boot Ubuntu Server 12.04 from a USB Device I have, and when I attempt to boot, I get "Boot Error"

Following a guide I saw ( http://www.planetmy.com/blog/how-to-configure-dell-server-bios-boot-from-usb/ ) I made sure USB's are enabled with BIOS support and it boots with the USB.
It seems to run on any other computer just fine.
Any solutions?

my server came with 2 SATA caddies installed, has 6GB DDR2 RAM with an intel xeon dual 2.8GHz processor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must insert the USB flash drive first, then power your server on.  Go to  Integrated Devices and check if USB is enabled with BIOS support , THEN check the Boot Sequence for a USB option. It should work for you.